# How to store an object that can be accessible globally in Spring

Tags: spring

Suppose I have a license file that will be loaded during startup. The data in the file will then be stored to a License object. How can I make this object accessible  to different components/services, the Spring way?

Comment: The Spring way is to autowire a singleton bean everywhere it is required

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. The easiest way is to do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class LicenseConfig {
  @Bean
  public MyLicense getLicense() {
    // Do stuff and return the license object.
  }
}
```

Then you can `@Autowire` the MyLicense object.

Answer (score 0):

If you build up your file as a property file you can access the data easily per `@Value`.

For example you create a property file with the following kv-pair: `value.from.file=TestTest`

```
@Value("${value.from.file}")
private String valueFromFile; // Contains TestTest
```

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Create Object and mark it with `@Configuration`. In your `application.properties` file, add entries for the file.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationLicense {

    @Value("${myapp.license.version}")
    String version;

    @Value("${myapp.license.code}")
    String license;

    @Value("${myapp.license.expiry}")
    String expiry;
}
```